# Creating a bash script to install packages

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, programming

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to bash. I'm trying to create a script that checks whether a package is installed or not. If not it will install that package. Not sure what I'm doing tbh.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo Installing/Checking packages from list

declare -a PKGS=("libreoffice", "firefox", "virtualbox", "vlc")
    
PKG_OK=$(dpkg-i -W --showformat='${Status}\n' PKGS |grep "install ok installed")


for i in "${PKGS[@]}"
do
    if [ "" = "$PKG_OK" ]; then
        echo "No $PKGS, installing the package now"
        sudo apt install $PKGS[@]
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'm quite the n00b with bash scripting, too. I find [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) extremely helpful.

Comment: Are you sure `dpkg` is the program you want? Most of the parameters you're using aren't in the man page.

Comment: Last comment for tonight: in case you're writing this script to do the job you want done and not as an exercise in bash scripting with arrays, you're making things hard on yourself. If you ask `apt` to install a package that's already installed, it just tells you it's already installed and tries the next one. It'd be fine if you just did `sudo apt install libreoffice firefox virtualbox vlc`.

Comment: Alright I will do that

Comment: I know I said the last comment was the last comment, but... you're asking `dpkg` the wrong question, I think. You're asking if a package *is* installed when you want to know if it *isn't* installed. Try `dpkg -s packagename 2>&1 | grep "not installed"` instead.

Comment: This looks overly complicated.

Comment: Your algorithm look good. Do you have an error? Share the log

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

pkgs=(libreoffice firefox virtualbox vlc)
sudo apt-get -y --ignore-missing install "${pkgs[@]}"
```

- the packages already installed will be ignored automatically
- those that are not accessible will be ignored too with `--ignore-missing`
- prefer `apt-get` than `apt` for scripting

From `man apt`:

> apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as
> an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared
> to more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8)

---

Another approach that I use personally, is to add every needed packages in a file *line by line*:

`packages.list`:

```
moreutils
util-linux
strace
```

Then I can call:

```
apt-get -y --ignore-missing install $(< packages.list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also a noob to shell scripting, honestly i don't know about your approach but this is what I would do instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a PKGS=(libreoffice firefox virtualbox vlc)
for i in "${PKGS[@]}"; do
    check=$(command -v "$i")
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        sudo apt install "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Not all packages are direct commands, one example: `command libreoffice-help-fr`. Testing if package is installed is _useless_

Comment: And if you need to test if a package is installed: `if dpkg -l | grep -wq <PACKAGE>; then echo installed; else echo not installed; fi` No need to test explicitely `$?`